# How to re-trigger loading UI in Next 13 using the new app directory?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am working with Next 13's `app` directory to build a simple website. The route to my main page is `/{username}?year={year}&month={month}`. When navigating to the page, the main section of this page  triggers the Loading UI from the `loading.tsx` file because it's making an API request. I have a selector in the page that allows the user to change the year and month. Upon changing these values, they get redirected to the same page, but with the updated date values: `/{username}?year={updatedYear}&month={updatedMonth}`. Once navigated, the Loading UI does not show again.

My `page` is a server component and consists of:

```
const year = searchParams.year;
const month = searchParams.month;

const userData = await getUserInfo(params.username);

return (
<main>
 ...
<Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
  <GameList {...{
    username: params.username,
    year,
    month,
    }} />
</Suspense>
</main>
);
```

My `<GameList />` component is also a Server Component and is defined as such:

```
const games = await getUserGames(username, year, month);

return (
 <some game data />
);
```

I have tried Next's `Link` to re-route the user to the page with the updated queries, where I used as such:

```
<Link href={`/${username}?year=${year}&month=${month}`}>component</Link>
```

I also tried using the `useRouter` from `next/navigation` with its `push` and `replace` functions:

```
router.replace(`/${username}?year=${year}&month=${month}`);
```

I have tried all the different caching strategies for my `fetch` calls, and that still hasn't changed anything. How can I get my `<GameList />` component to go into Loading state again once the date changes (when it makes a new API request to fill with new data)?

Entry point to the page: [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mir-mirsodikov/chesscom-analysis/blob/main/app/%5Busername%5D/page.tsx).